# Blender DMX Exporting Issues: Japanese Text in Files

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm very new to blender and I am trying my darndest to convert a MMD pmx file to dmx file for use in Source Filmmaker and GMod. I got the first part down and exported the pmx file to a blender file thanks to the mmd_tools add-on:

[image]

[image]

however now I’ve hit a brick wall when trying to use the blender source tools to export it to a dmx file as you can see from the messages to the bottom left here:

[image]

The end result is deformed and discolored

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Or am I going about this in a fundamentally wrong way and missing steps?